# Find angle in degrees from one point to another in 2D space?

Tags: geometry

Given Point A and Point B in 2D space, how can I find the angle Point B is from Point A? 0° can be any direction; it doesn't matter. For example, Point A is at `(0, 10)` and Point B is at `(10, 20)`. The angle is 45° in this example (assuming 0° is up).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe that the accepted answer does not correctly solve the problem for many people visiting this question. I am doing 2D simulations and the answer above does not solve my problem. Imagine the following circle:

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

Assume that the middle of the circle is point A. Point B is at some angle from A according to the angles of the circle (so 0°) is right.

$\hskip2in$**The atan2 function is what you need!**

$$ atan2(y, x) $$
$\hskip3.2in$ Where

$$ y = y_B - y_A $$
$$ x = x_B - x_A $$

[Read more about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: You made my day. I spent hours trying to figure this out and got nothing but convoluted solutions that never return a proper angle. Thank you!

Comment: Is x1,y1 point A, and x2,y2 point B?

Comment: @SteveSmith yes.

Comment: Maybe this is useful to someone: https://justingolden.me/angleto/

Comment: Note that some implementations are ${\rm atan2}(\Delta x,\,\Delta y)$ and some ${\rm atan2}(\Delta y,\,\Delta x)$. Check your documentation.

Answer (score 11):

From what I understood about your question, you want to find the angle between two points given their coordinates. In that case, first find the slope of the line using the slope formula:
$$m=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$
where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are coordinates on the line. Next, use this formula:
$$\tan(\theta)=m$$
where $\theta$ is the angle. Therefore, the angle $\theta$ equals:
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}(m)$$

---

Let's use the points $(0,10)$ and $(10,20)$ as an example (you mentioned it in your question). The slope is:
$$m=\dfrac{10-20}{0-10}$$
$$m=\dfrac{-10}{-10}$$
$$m=1$$
Now we will find $\theta$.
$$\tan(\theta)=1$$
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}(1)$$
$$\theta=45^\circ$$

---

**Note:** The $\tan(\theta)=m$ formula only gives the angle facing the positive $x$-axis (i.e. facing the "right"). So for a negative slope, you should get an angle that is greater than $90^\circ$.

Comment: In your example using my two points you used the Xs over the Ys. Is that intentional? Why does it differ from the equation above?

Comment: @Keavon Nice observation, it is supposed to be the Ys over the Xs, sorry

Comment: What about the scenario where A = (10, 0) and B = (10, 10), and so x2-y2 = 0 and you get a divide by 0 error? This isn't a paticularly helpful answer imo.

Comment: Does this answer work if point B is to the left of point A?